# Include SharePoint attachements inline within one report

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

How can I batch print all items in a list including attached documents (word. pdf)?

So functionally I need: *one* report/document which includes all info from attached documents *inline* within that report. The user only has to print out that single report.

Could it be done with Reporting Services? Or a commercial component?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a script to merge the word documents, or to print all the documents. Reporting services helps you generate the documents not in merging them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a component such as [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) you can create all of the applicable reports and then bundle them into a single PDF and return them to the user.  I've done this for a number of projects and it works great.  I was also able to join PDFs generated from SSRS with some PDF documents from other sources.